# Synchronising the execution of a function as callback parameter in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback

I'm learning js (specifically node&express), and currently struggling to apprehend what exactly is sync and what isn't.

Currently I have let's say A-type sevices that needs to send requests to B-type services.
I wanted to aggregate these requests in a common function so that all A-type services would use it.

A-type service code (directly in router.post)

```
var post_data = <some data>
sendBServicePost(post_data,function (out_data) {
    var resp_data = JSON.parse(out_data);
    if (resp_data.status == "OK") {
      var msg = 'Request OK : '+out_data;
      console.log(msg);
      res.json({ status:"OK", message:msg});
    }
    else
    {
      var msg = 'Login KO: '+out_data;
      console.log(msg);
      res.json({ status:"KO_FUNC", message:msg});
    }
  }).on('error',function (e) {
    var msg = 'Error with call: ' + e.message;
    console.log(msg);
    res.json({ status:"KO_TECH", message:msg});
  });
```

And here's the code of the culprit function :

```
function sendBServicePost(post_data,callback) {
    var post_options = {
        // Some options
    };

    // Sending request
    var post_req = http.request(post_options, function(post_res) {
        post_res.on('data', function(out_data) {
          callback(out_data);
        });
    });
    post_req.write(post_data);
    post_req.end();
}
```

So, what's happening is I get the error saying I'm trying to add response headers while the response has already been sent, which I assume is happening because the execution of A-type service has finished before the callback function code has been reached
.
I thought callbacks were stacked and execution would go through the full stack, so it's hard for me to tell what exactly is async in this chain.

Could someone please shed some light on this matter? How could I synchronize this chain? Some best practices here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core problem you are seeing now is that `'data'` events can fire multiple times with pieces of the data, so you will be calling `callback` multiple times, and therefore calling `res.json` multiple times, which triggers your error.

Also, `node` has generally standardized on code that passes callbacks to use the first param as the error, so I'd recommend the following:

```
function sendBServicePost(post_data, callback) {
    var post_options = {
        // Some options
    };

    // Sending request
    var post_req = http.request(post_options, function(post_res) {
        var pieces = [];
        post_res.on('data', function(out_data) {
            pieces.push(out_data);
        });
        post_res.on('end' function(){
            callback(null, Buffer.concat(pieces));
        });
        post_res.on('error', function(err){
            callback(err, null);
        });
    });
    post_req.on('error', function(err){
        callback(err, null);
    });

    post_req.write(post_data);
    post_req.end();
}
```

Called like:

```
var post_data = <some data>
sendBServicePost(post_data, function (err, out_data) {
    if (err){
        var msg = 'Error with call: ' + e.message;
        res.json({ status: "KO_TECH", message: msg});
        return;
    }

    var resp_data = JSON.parse(out_data);
    if (resp_data.status == "OK") {
        var msg = 'Request OK : ' + out_data;
        res.json({status: "OK", message: msg});
    } else {
        var msg = 'Login KO: ' + out_data;
        res.json({status: "KO_FUNC", message: msg});
    }
  });
```

If you really want code more like `.on('error',`, then you could always return an event-emitter object from `sendBServicePost`, but then I'd also recommend reworking your callback to be event-based so you don't mix paradigms.

Comment: Oh, so that's what it was about ! All's working like charm now, thank you for putting me on the correct path.

Answer (score 0):

```
function sendBServicePost(post_data,callback) {
    var post_options = {
        // Some options
    };

    // << While this part is executing >>
    var post_req = http.request(post_options, function(post_res) {
        post_res.on('data', function(out_data) {
          // Anything you want to execute synchronously you can write here, before or after callback.
          callback(out_data);
        });
    });

    // << This part is also executing >>
    post_req.write(post_data);
    post_req.end();
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion - but this would require passing 'res' and implementing here the A-response generation rules based on output directly in this "helper" function. I'd want to avoid that, making this function only responsible for making B-service calls - and delegating B-response treatment to the caller.

Comment: But when you are calling `callback(out_data);` then only the **A-type service code** is executing and setting the response data but why are you doing this `post_req.write(post_data);` `post_req.end();`

Comment: Actually declaring post_req like this doesn't do anything, it is only when you execute .end() method that the request is issued